# Html encoding with TextBoxFor MVC 4

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-encode

Whenever I enter anything in < angle brackets > (as well as some other html syntaxy things) into my `TextBoxFor` an exception is thrown

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.tags, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "tags (comma separated)" })
```

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (tags="").

I understand this occurs to prevent insecurities and that html encoding/decoding is the solution to my issue but I'm not sure how to implement it.

I've read in a few places that `TextBoxFor` does html encoding by default, but if that's true why am I having this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent this warning your have to put the `[AllowHtml()]` attribute on the tags property of your viewmodel.