# Html encoding TextboxFor input

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model-view-controller, html-encode

Please bare with my ignorance for now as I have just started learning web related programming. So, I have a web project written in MVC that has a login window with Username textbox bound to a property:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new {@placeholder = "Username"})
```

As I understand, Razor automatically html encodes input to help preventing cross-script attacks. However, when I test username with a javascript I get an exception from MVC:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the
>   client (UserName="...hp?name_1=code

Which makes me think that the input is NOT html encoded. My idea was to resolve this issue with html encoding/decoding but looks like I am not getting this whole idea right. Could someone explain?

**NOTE:** one of SO's [related posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943455/html-encoding-with-textboxfor-mvc-4) provides an unsecured solution but it is not an option for me to simply allow html.

Answer (score 0):

It is not HTML encoded, that is correct. You will have to do the HTML encoding in the Action that form posts back to.

Also, you will need to add [ValidateInput(false)] attribute just about your action.